# ¿Como obtener el value de un input usando closest en Jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo una tabla, en la cual tengo cientos de filas, y en la que cada fila se ve algo así (con información diferente para cada fila, por supuesto)

```
<tr>
    <input class="prodId" hidden value="<?php echo $product['id']; ?>">
    <td class="thead"><?php echo $product['prod_name']; ?></td>
    <td class="thead"><?php echo $product['prod_price']; ?></td>
    <td class="thead"><?php echo $product['prod_qty']; ?></td>
    <td class="thead">
        <select class="availability-options">
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Todo esta funcionando bien en el evento de cambio de opción del `select`. Lo que estoy intentando hacer es obtener el valor del id que esta en el `input`. Estoy intentando esto

```
$(".availability-options").on("change", function(){
    let optionSelected = $(this).val();
    let _id = $(this).closest("input .prodId").val();
    ....
```

Y también intente esto

```
let _id = $(this).parent().parent().children(".prodId").val();
```

Entiendo que ambos selectores devuelven un objeto tipo Jquery, pero no logro entender como obtener el `value` del `input`. Siempre me retorna un valor indefinido. ¿Como obtengo el valor del `input`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el `input`: lo declaras  como `hidden`, lo correcto es `type="hidden"`. Lo probé como lo tienes y me marcaba *undefined* como dices.

Por otro lado, `closest` asciende en la jerarquía del DOM para encontrar el elemento que se indica (buscando su ancestro). En este caso, nunca encontrará al `input` como su ancestro. Por lo tanto, ascendemos al `tr` y ahí buscamos el `input` como hijo:

```js
$(".availability-options").on("change", function(){
    let optionSelected = $(this).val();
    var id = $(this).closest("tr").children("input.prodId").val();
    console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <input class="prodId" type="hidden" value="xvalue">
    <td class="thead">name</td>
    <td class="thead">price</td>
    <td class="thead">qti</td>
    <td class="thead">
        <select class="availability-options">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Correcto, la solucion es tu nota extra. Por alguna extraña razon cuando escribo solo hidden sale undefined y cuando se escribe type="hidden" si funciona. Que extraño. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Ya quedó editado aclarando el problema real y la solución

Comment: Excelente. Alguna idea de porque se da esto? Creo que vale la pena una pregunta para aclararlo.

Comment: Probablemente es por que los nombres de atributos tienen la nomenclatura **atributo="valor"**. Si no tienen este valor, *hidden* se toma como el nombre del tag y ese tag no existe. Debe ser eso. Si la respuesta te sirvió no olvides marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: El undefined sale por lo que puse en mi respuesta. Con type=hidden el navegador mantiene el elemento en el DOM pero sin eso lo mueve fuera de la tabla, por lo que el selector falla en encontrarlo.

Answer (score -1):

Intenta de la siguiente forma:

```js
var value = $('.prodId').val();
console.log(value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="prodId" disable hidden value="<?php echo $product['id']; ?>">
```

Te dejo la documentación de Jquery para este caso
http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Jaime, agradezco tu respuesta. Creo que me falto ser un poco especifico en mi pregunta, ya que tengo cientos de filas y debo obtener el input especifico que esta en la fila donde estoy presionando el select. Hacerlo como has indicado me devolveria un arreglo con todos los input de mi pagina complicando las cosas. Pero gracias de igual forma, fue mi culpa. Ya he editado la pregunta.

Answer (score -1):

Prueba eliminando el espacio en el selector `$(this).closest("input.prodId")`

Además, me parece que los `input` no quedarán renderizados donde deberían si los agregas como hijos de un `tr`. Yo los movería al mismo `td` del `select`

Comment: Klaimmore, gracias por tu respuesta. Te aconsejo que leas la documentacion oficial de los [selectores en Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Mi input tiene el atributo hidden, asi que no mucho entiendo a que te refieres con renderizar.

Comment: Input no es un elemento permitido como hijo de un tr. Puede ser que el navegador lo mueva a otra parte del DOM, en particular después de la tabla. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-tr-element

Answer (score -2):

El closest no funciona porque el input no es hijo del select 
ejemplo: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_closest.asp

Intenta usar mediante una función

```js
function getId(value){
  console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<tr>
    <!--<input class="prodId" disable hidden value="<?php echo $product['id']; ?>">-->
    <td class="thead"><?php echo $product['prod_name']; ?></td>
    <td class="thead"><?php echo $product['prod_price']; ?></td>
    <td class="thead"><?php echo $product['prod_qty']; ?></td>
    <td class="thead">
        <!--<select class="availability-options" onClick="getId('<?php echo $product['id']; ?>')">-->
        <select class="availability-options" onClick="getId(2)">
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Bueno creo que seria por un onChange

Comment: Jaime, de nuevo gracias. Como se puede observar en mi segunda opcion, claramente estoy haciendo referencia a los elementos "padres" del select usando parent(). Por supuesto que el input no es hijo del select. Tambien es de suma importancia para este sitio, SOes, que si la pregunta tiene una etiqueta de alguna tecnologia, las respuestas deben ser acorde a esa tecnologia. Tu respuesta solo con javascript solo te hara merecer votos negativos. Saludos.